# WPF Multibinding with Source and Path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multibinding

I am writing the below code for implementing a Multibinding in WPF textblock

```
<TextBlock> 
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding  StringFormat="{}{0}-{1}">
                <Binding Source="{Binding Path=localResource.bookdata_labelPageNO,Source={StaticResource LanguageManagerDynamic}}"/>
                <Binding Path="PageNo"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
```

I am trying to load a string like "Page xx" where xx is the page number which is a property of  the binded model and the string "Page" is loaded from the resource 
But i am getting runtime error on this line @ XAML . What is causing the error ?

This was my previous working code

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding PageNo,StringFormat=page. {0}}" />
```

Comment: Try with Run Text in Textblock

Comment: Care to open up the LanguageManagerDynamic usage?

Answer (score 0):

Ok for pure xaml solution you can do this, assuming your resources are loaded properly.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="Page">Page</sys:String>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding  StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource Page}"/>
            <Binding Path="PageNo" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Can we do it in xaml alone? Like my working piece of code ?

Comment: Hmm the issue seems to be your resource loading, why it is so complicated?

Comment: You have to write your own MultiValueConverter by deriving from IMultiValueConverter, because the default converter seems to get "confused" about different sources (e. g. "StaticResource Page" and "PageNo" have not the same origin), even if both are strings.

Answer (score 0):

Can You try Like this

```
<TextBlock>
     <Run Text="Page" />
      <Run Text="{Binding PageNo}" />
  </TextBlock>
```